# transfering contacts from my old phone to iPhone via Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, contacts

Is it possible to transfer all my contacts from my old phone to iPhone via Bluetooth?

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately this isn't possible as the iPhone lacks the necessary Bluetooth services for address book transfer. If both your iPhone and previous phone are GSM phones, you can transfer the contacts to the SIM and transfer them off with the iPhone.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's sad because there isn't enough memory for all contacts on SIM.

Comment: @Gigili You can always do multiple transfers

Comment: Right, it wouldn't be as easy as only one!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647), the closest supported Bluetooth profile is Phone Book Access Profile (PBAP), but this is mainly used with car kits to:

> - Allow the car kit to display the name of the incoming caller
> - Allow the car kit to download the phone book so the user can initiate a call from the car display

There is no mention of sending contacts to the iPhone. You might be able to find something on Cydia with a Jailbroken phone, though. For example, the [iBluetooth app](http://www.simonblog.com/2009/03/12/bluetooth-file-transfer-iphone-ibluetooth/) adds file syncing capabilities. However, it doesn't mention anything about contact syncing.